# How to raise error if cap deploy was not invoked using bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I just encountered a subtle issue with capistrano deployment gem dependencies and I would like to enforce how capistrano is invoked.

How can I detect that capistrano was invoked using 'bundle exec' like this:

```
bundle exec cap app deploy
```

And not like this:

```
cap app deploy
```

I would like to raise an error in the latter case by detecting the method of invocation at the top of my deploy.rb file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that Bundler sets the $BUNDLE_BIN_PATH and $BUNDLE_GEMFILE environment variables when running executables.  For example, do this:

```
env >/tmp/1
bundler exec env >/tmp/2
diff -u /tmp/[12]
```

You'll see the differences in the environment.

So then in your deployment script, you can do something like this:

```
abort "You must run this using 'bundle exec ...'" unless ENV['BUNDLE_BIN_PATH'] || ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']
```

Hope this helps.